# How to remove multiple-lined strings using bash?

Tags: text-processing, grep

consider this string:

**file**

```
This is some text
<#
Love this or that
#>
He is running like a rabbit
```

In order to, for example, grep for newline strings, id use:

```
cat file | grep -Pzo '(?s)<#.*?#>'
```

Which will output:

```
<#
Love this or that
#>
```

But what if i want to **REMOVE** the match? how can I do it?

Comment: Is `pcregrep` available on your system?

Comment: ... or GNU grep? In that case, `grep -P ...` *is* `pcregrep` (afaik).

Comment: I got a GNU grep, also using it in the example with -P

Comment: bash is just your shell; it's not a text editor.

Comment: Perhaps read up on `sed` and `awk` as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `sed`

```
sed '/<#/,/#>/d' file
```

It removing text between two specific strings.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that.

Comment: I think you should anchor your patterns to the beginning of the line, otherwise it will also delete lines in which the pattern occurs "as part of the text", so to speak.

Comment: Note that it removes the whole lines starting from the one that contains `<#` up to the next one after it that contains `#>` (or the end of the file if not found), so it would also delete `foo` in `foo <#` and wouldn't work for `<# foo #>`

Answer (score 2):

That `-P` (a GNU extension) is for `P`erl regexps actually, so:

```
<file perl -0777 -pe 's/<#.*?#>//sg'
```

Comment: What should i do then??

Comment: @toto333, well, run that command.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be `grep`, you can do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {p=1}; $1 == "<#" {p=0}; $1 == "#>" {p=1; next}; p == 1 {print}' file
```

This will set an internal flag `p` to 1 at the beginning, set it to `0` once your "exclusion start" pattern is found, and sets it back to 1 when encountering the "exclusion end". It will then only print lines where p equals 1. The `next` statement in the rule for matching the end is necessary to prevent the end pattern from being printed.

Comment: Im not sure how to read this and it doesnt work on my example

Comment: If I copy the example content you posted into a file called `file`, then the command-line I posted prints out all lines except those between `<#` and `#>`. Could you specify if you get any error messages?

Comment: Golfed: `$1 == "<#" {p=1} !p; $1 == "#>" {p=0}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is elegant, I put it under consideration:

```
tr "\n" "%" < file | sed -e 's/<#%.*#>%//' | tr "%" "\n"
```

---

Replace new lines with `%`

```
tr "\n" "%"
```

---

Replace everthing between `<#%...#>%`:

```
sed -e 's/<#%.*#>%//'
```

---

Replace `%` with new lines:

```
tr "$" "\n"
```

---

Ouput:

```
This is some text
He is running like a rabbit
```